# "Missing ( keyword" When create table with column identity in Oracle12c

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, create-table

Can you explain what is my mistake ?

```
create table ABC.t1 (
    c1 NUMBER GENERATED ALWAYS as IDENTITY ( START with 1 INCREMENT by 1 ),
    c2 VARCHAR2(10)
    )
```

> Error report -
>   ORA-02000: missing ( keyword
>   02000. 00000 -  "missing %s keyword"

[image]

Comment: That works in 12c and above. It looks like you are still running it on Oracle11g. Please check the output of `select * from v$version` from your session.

Answer (score 2):

The "generated as identity" feature works on or after Oracle 12c.

Prior to Oracle 12c:

```
create table t1 (
    c1 NUMBER,
    c2 VARCHAR2(10)
    );

create sequence
   t1_seq
  increment by 1
  start with 1;

Insert into
   t1
values
   (t1_seq.nextval, 'ABC');
```

In or After Oracle 12c:

```
create table ABC.t1 (
    c1 NUMBER GENERATED ALWAYS as IDENTITY ( START with 1 INCREMENT by 1 ),
    c2 VARCHAR2(10)
    );

Insert into
   t1
values
   ('ABC');
```

So, your statement will only work on 12c or later.

Comment: thank you. I already installed oracle 12c and finished. thankyou so much

Comment: most welcome. please accept the answer if you think it solved your question. :-)

Comment: create sequence page_views_t_GUID_ID cache 1e6;

--Create Table page_views_t
create table page_views_t (
 integervalue_c NUMBER GENERATED ALWAYS as IDENTITY ( START with 1 INCREMENT by 1 ),
 rowid_c constraint page_views_t_GUID_ID primary key
) AS
SELECT sys_guid()
from xmltable('1 to 10000000');

Comment: I am creating like that but identity column error is coming  ORA-02000: missing ( keyword

Comment: my version is 18c XE. is it 11g or 12c or above 12c or below 12c?